# How to disable specific plugin on Wordpress backend / edit product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to find a solution to disable specific plugins on Wordpress admin area. The problem is that for building WooCommerce shops I use Divi Builder, which on product page can sometimes use 50mb of resources when you try to edit it... if I disable some plugins over there then the load time would be much faster. I've found the following code on other topic:

```
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'lg_disable_cart66_plugin' );

function lg_disable_cart66_plugin($plugins){

      if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/store/') === FALSE AND strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin/') === FALSE) {
         $key = array_search( 'cart66/cart66.php' , $plugins );
         if ( false !== $key ) unset( $plugins[$key] );
      }

      return $plugins;
 }
```

But don't know how to modify it, so it only disables the chosen plugin on backend. In other words: I don't want the plugin to load when I edit WooCommerce product page.

Some help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As ‘option_active_plugins’ is fired before any plugin is loaded we need to drop our code down into [mu-plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) directory. Please also remember that those plugins are run before the main query is initialized – that is why we don’t have any access to many functionalities, especially conditional tags which will always return false.

Please paste below code or download [gist](https://gist.github.com/musamamasood/f9e3a3ff04e992ce0fc777536df8ffd2) in **mu-plugins** folder in your wp-content folder. It would disable the plugin in post & page areas only.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Disable Plugin for URl
Plugin URI: https://www.glowlogix.com
Description: Disable plugins for for specific backend pages.
Author: Muhammad Usama M.
Version: 1.0.0
*/
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'disable_plugins_per_page' );
function disable_plugins_per_page( $plugin_list ) {

    // Quit immediately if not post edit area.
    global $pagenow;
    if (( $pagenow == 'post.php' || $pagenow == 'edit.php' )) {
        $disable_plugins = array (
            // Plugin Name
            'hello.php',
            'developer/developer.php'
        );
        $plugins_to_disable = array();
        foreach ( $plugin_list as $plugin ) {
            if ( true == in_array( $plugin, $disable_plugins ) ) {
                //error_log( "Found $plugin in list of active plugins." );
                $plugins_to_disable[] = $plugin;
            }
        }
        // If there are plugins to disable then remove them from the list,
        // otherwise return the original list.
        if ( count( $plugins_to_disable ) ) {
            $new_list = array_diff( $plugin_list, $plugins_to_disable );
            return $new_list;
        }   
    }
    return $plugin_list;
}
```

You can replace **$disable_plugins** with the required list of plugins to disable.

Comment: Okay, I just tested with WordPress and working perfect. If possible, please share error_log message after it crash.

Comment: any idea how to do it? When I use it I can't access my dashboard anymore

Comment: I have improved the solution and created mu-plugin to cater your requirement.

Comment: Many thanks for it! Although it still doesn't work properly:-S For example I tried to disbable Query Monitor plugin on edit page. It disappeared from the top menu bar, but it still loads its JS and CSS which slows the edit page waaay down: https://take.ms/tM6TF

I use Divi Builder here, and when all the plugins are active, on the edit page it can use like 47MB of resources (in Chrome Dev Network tab: https://take.ms/EWVvk). It's insane so I must limit it somehow:(

When I disable the plugin manually from the plugins page, they don't load their CSS and JS..